# Compiling FAPWS3 on Windows 7?

Tags: python, windows, compilation, fapws3

I found no information whatsoever on how to install [FAPWS3](http://www.fapws.org/) on my Win7 machine.

Help would be immensely appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

3 years later, the answer is still probably that FAPWS is linux only.